# Why is only one index used

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE timedevent
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  eventdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  newstateids character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  sourceid character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT timedevent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

with PK `id`.

I have to query rows between two dates with certain newstate and source from a set of possible sources.

I created a btree indexes on `eventdate` and `newstateids` and one more (hash index) on `sourceid`. Only the index on `date` made the queries faster - it seems the other two are not used. Why is that so? How could I make my queries faster?

```
CREATE INDEX eventdate_index     ON timedevent USING btree (eventdate);
CREATE INDEX newstateids_index   ON timedevent USING btree (newstateids COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX sourceid_index_hash ON timedevent USING hash  (sourceid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Here is the query as Hibernate generates it:

```
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.description as descript2_0_0_, this_.eventDate as eventDat3_0_0_, this_.locationId as location4_0_0_, this_.newStateIds as newState5_0_0_, this_.oldStateIds as oldState6_0_0_, this_.sourceId as sourceId7_0_0_ 
from TimedEvent this_
where ((this_.newStateIds=? and this_.sourceId in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)))
    and this_.eventDate between ? and ?
    limit ?
```

EDIT:
Sorry for the misleading title but it seem postges uses all indexes. The problem is my query time still remains the same. Here ist the query plan I got:

```
Limit  (cost=25130.29..33155.77 rows=321 width=161) (actual time=705.330..706.744 rows=279 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6 read=8167 written=61
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on timedevent this_  (cost=25130.29..33155.77 rows=321 width=161) (actual time=705.330..706.728 rows=279 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (((sourceid)::text = ANY ('{"root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Bad","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Alarmruf","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 1","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 2","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Zimmer" (...)
        Filter: ((eventdate >= '2017-11-01 15:41:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (eventdate <= '2018-03-20 14:58:16.724+01'::timestamp with time zone))
        Buffers: shared hit=6 read=8167 written=61
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25130.29..25130.29 rows=2122 width=0) (actual time=232.990..232.990 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=6 read=2152
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sourceid_index_hash  (cost=0.00..1403.36 rows=39182 width=0) (actual time=1.195..1.195 rows=9308 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((sourceid)::text = ANY ('{"root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Bad","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Alarmruf","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 1","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 2","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Z (...)
                    Buffers: shared hit=6 read=26
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on state_index  (cost=0.00..23726.53 rows=777463 width=0) (actual time=231.160..231.160 rows=776520 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((newstateids)::text = 'ACTIV'::text)
                    Buffers: shared read=2126
Total runtime: 706.804 ms
```

After creating an index using btree on (sourceid, newstateids) as a_horse_with_no_name suggested, the cost reduced:

```
Limit  (cost=125.03..8150.52 rows=321 width=161) (actual time=13.611..14.454 rows=279 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=18 read=4336
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on timedevent this_  (cost=125.03..8150.52 rows=321 width=161) (actual time=13.609..14.432 rows=279 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (((sourceid)::text = ANY ('{"root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Bad","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Alarmruf","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 1","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 2","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Zimmer","r (...)
        Filter: ((eventdate >= '2017-11-01 15:41:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (eventdate <= '2018-03-20 14:58:16.724+01'::timestamp with time zone))
        Buffers: shared hit=18 read=4336
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on src_state_index  (cost=0.00..124.95 rows=2122 width=0) (actual time=0.864..0.864 rows=4526 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((sourceid)::text = ANY ('{"root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Bad","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Alarmruf","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 1","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Bett Alarm 2","root,kus-chemnitz,ize-159,Anwesend Zimmer (...)
              Buffers: shared hit=18 read=44
Total runtime: 14.497 ms"
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** `create index` statements you used and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: <s>Because only one index can be used at once.</s>

Comment: @zerkms: that's not true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for this very query more than one index could be used for the lookups?

Comment: Postgres does have the possibility to use e.g. a bitmap index scan for the `IN` condition and another index for the `between` condition. Whether that makes sense and the planner actually chooses to do so depends on many different factors. But the general statement "only one index is used" is wrong.

Comment: A single (btree) index on `(newstateids, sourceid)` might be a better choice then two single-column indexes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in real world, is it frequent to rely on optimiser to do the right job and be smart enough to use multiple indexes instead of using a composite index? (not being snarky, a genuine question from a developer to a db expert)

Comment: @zerkms: yes, if that means creating less or smaller indexes (e.g. because those indexes can be used for more queries than just one)

Comment: As I said before: please show us the execution  plan generated with **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** not just a plain `explain` output.

Comment: Sorry about the missing (analyze, buffers). Now I know what you mean, Tried index on (sourceid, newstateids) and its 2x faster than before.

Answer (score 0):

Basically only one index is used because database would have to combine your indexes into one so that they would be useful (or combine results from searches over more indexes) and doing this is so expensive, that it in this case chooses not to and use just one of the indexes relevant for one predicate and check the other predicates directly on values in found rows.

***One B-tree index with several columns would work better, just as a_horse_with_no_name suggests in comments***. Also note, that order of columns matter a lot (columns that are used for single value search should be first, the one for range search later, you want to **limit range searches** as much as possible). 
Then databese will go through index, looking for rows that satisfy on predicate using the first column of index (hopefully narrowing the numbers of rows a lot) and the the second column and second predicate come to play, ...

Using separate B-tree indexes when predicates are combined using AND operator does not make sense to database, because it would have to use one index to choose all rows, which satisfy one predicate and then, it would have to use another index, read its blocks (where the index is stored) from disk again, only to get to rows which satisfy the condition relevant to this second index, but possibly not the other condition. And if they satisfy it, it's probably cheaper to just load the row after first using index and check the other predicates directly, not using index.